# Как написать в канал гильдии дискорда api discord без библиотек

Tags: python

не нашёл метода для отправки сообщений текстовые каналы гильдии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользуйтесь `GET` и `POST` запросами к API Дискорда, вот ссылка -> https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

1. Необходимо создать приложение [здесь](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
2. Подключаем бота к нашему приложению.
3. Приглашаем бота на нужную гильдию.
4. Пишем код

```
# Импортируем модули
import requests

# Объявляем переменные
TOKEN = '123' # Токен бота которого мы создали
CHANNEL_ID = 123 # ID необходимого канала

# Создаём запрос
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bot {TOKEN}'}
response = requests.post(f'https://discord.com/api//channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/messages',  data={'content':'Привет! Это тестовое сообщение!'}, headers=headers)
```

5. Готово!

**P.S.** Ссылка на документацию к запросу на создание сообщения -> https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message

Comment: а зачем идти по кривой, если напрямик легче и удобнее.

Comment: о неплохо, помогло, слушай, а не подскажешь, как написать пользователю имея, только его id